# How to read visual studio code intellisense syntax hint, any document for operators?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

VSC like VS gives out syntax/signature hint. I understand **:** means data type

```
myText: string  // : means datatype of myText is string
myStuff: any    // any means can be any data type.
```

sometimes hard to guess what the operators mean, for example the Node's request(), 
[image]

my understanding is

1. `const request` means I can define any variable like `const x=request(...)` or `var x=request(...)`.
2. `request.RequestAPI` means it's an API call.
3. `options:` defines this parameter is a typical object-like options in form of `{...}`
4. `(request.UriOptions & request.CoreOptions)` I understand the beginning and end parts, they must be enum of Uri and Core, but what is `&`? Does it mean I need to supply both Uri **AND** Core?
5. `|` does this pipe mean **OR**? If it is then it's duplicating the part before the pipe.
6. `callback?: request.RequestCallback`, so here I must provide a callback which will be typed (or functioning) as RequestCallback, but what is `?:`?

Is there any document for these conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to comment, because I don't know the complete answer, but here is some helpful information:

You are probably seeing this definition of DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/request/index.d.ts#L29

Have a look at this to understand the definition file syntax: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

And you can interpret the definition like this:

`const request:` there is a constant named *request* that implements the interface `request.RequestAPI` (which is also callable directly and then for that) takes arguments `options` of type `(request.UriOptions & request.CoreOptions) | (request.UrlOptions & request.CoreOptions)` and an optional parameter `callback` (hence the `?` of type `request.RequestCallback`. The function returns a `request.Request`.

- `&` usually mean *and*
- A pipe `|` usually means *or*, there is no duplication *URI* vs *URL*
- `=>` "returns"
- You see `request` in front of everything because it's the namespace (my wording may be off here)

The definitions of `UriOptions`, `UrlOptions`, `CoreOptions` are buried a bit. I'm not a node user, so I don't know what you can pass to request.
For example `UrlOptions` can either be a string argument named "url" or a `url` (from `require('url')`). See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/request/index.d.ts#L162

Comment: Based on my knowledge, `var` and `const` are the same, at least to me they are. Good point, URI and URL, I overlooked that.

Comment: Still don't know what `?` before `:` is for.

Comment: @Jeb50 The ```?``` marks an optional parameter, see my answer after "an optional parameter ```callback``` (hence the ```?``` ..."